# Reference for Wold-Decomposition Theorem (Operator Theory)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I'm looking for full proves for the following theorems:

1. (**Wold-decomposition theorem 1954.**) Every isometry is a direct sum of unitary and unilateral shifts.
2. Every isometry is unitary equivalent to a direct sum of unitary and unilateral shifts.

Here is a sketched proof from Wikipedia for (1).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_decomposition#A_sequence_of_isometries

Can I get some suggestions or references for the full proofs?

$\bf{EDIT}$: From the comments, (2) implies (1), because of the orthogonal decomposition of the space.. I still don't really see why. Could someone help me on this part?

Thank you!

Comment: Nagy/Foias/Bercovici/Kerchy, Theorem 1.1

Comment: A side question: what is "a direct subtraction" when you say $M_i = H_i \ominus H_{i-1}$?

Comment: If $U = V\oplus M$, then $U\ominus V := M$.

Comment: Do you happen to know a reference for the second theorem (just added) ? Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't #2 implied by #1?

Comment: Does equivalence imply unitary equivalence?

Comment: #2 is the Wold decomposition because the space decomposition is orthogonal.

Comment: Sorry I still don't see why the orthogonal decomposition of the space gives us that unitary equivalence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $T : H\rightarrow H$ is an isometric linear map on a Hilbert space $H$, meaning that $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$ for all $x\in H$. Then $T$ is bounded, with an adjoint $T^*$ such that $T^*T=I$ because the polarization identity gives
\begin{align}
         \langle T^*Tx,y\rangle &= \langle Tx,Ty\rangle \\
       &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n\langle T(x+i^ny),T(x+i^ny)\rangle= \\
       &= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n\langle x+i^ny,x+i^ny\rangle 
       =\langle x,y\rangle, \;\;\; x,y\in H.
\end{align}
$TH=H$ iff $T$ is unitary. If $TH\ne H$, there exists a unit vector $x\in H$ such that $x\perp TH$. Then $\{ x,Tx,T^2x,\cdots \}$ is an orthonormal subset of $H$ on which $T$ is a simple shift operator. If $x\perp y$ and $x,y\perp TH$, then $[\{ x,Tx,T^2x,\cdots\}]$ and $[\{y,Ty,T^2y,\cdots\}]$ are mutually orthogonal sets on which $T$ is a unilateral shift. There are as many copies of such shifts as there are in an orthonormal basis of $(TH)^{\perp}$. What's left over is $Y=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}T^n H$. This is a closed invariant subspace of $T$, and $T$ is unitary on this subspace because $TY=Y$, though $Y=\{0\}$ may occur. Together this gives a decomposition of the space into a subspace where $T$ is unitary, and a collection of mutually orthogonal invariant subspaces of $T$ on which $T$ is a unilateral shift.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could I ask why this implies that every isometry is also unitarily equivalent to the direct sum?

Comment: Also, if $T$ is not unitary, why do we know that there exists a unit vector $x\in H$ such that $x \perp TH$?

Comment: @Korn : Because $TH$ is a closed subspace.